# I deployed my rails app to heroku but I get an error upon viewing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My rails app works fine locally however on heroku it is not working. When I run heroku logs everything seems to be fine except for this line:

`2015-02-04T01:46:56.345454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intense-everglades-8966.herokuapp.com request_id=43dd88ab-bf6a-4eea-978c-3ba43ed561c2 fwd="98.225.171.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=`

Comment: The answer is definitely somewhere in your logs. Keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

The message you got returned the error code H10, which means that the App crashed.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

There is not much help available to troubleshoot that on Heroku website. The crash could be due to multiple reasons.
However, you can get more clues on what is wrong with :

```
$heroku run rails console
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Running a Rails console will be of no use in this situation.